# Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.BlobColumn' to type 'System.Byte[]'

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a script that takes a file (usually image or pdf) from an SQL array, and if necessary decompresses it, and then copies its content to another cell. However, for reasons that I do not understand, the program fails for some uncompressed files with the error: `Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.BlobColumn' to type 'System.Byte[]'.`.

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    if (Row.bitCompressed)
    {

        byte[] inputData = Row.imgFileContent.GetBlobData(0, (int)Row.imgFileContent.Length);
        Row.FileImageOut.AddBlobData(Decompress(inputData));

    }
    else
    {

        Row.FileImageOut = Row.imgFileContent; <--- ERROR
    }
}
```

The `Row.FilmeImageOur` is a `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.BlobColumn Input0Buffer.FileImageOut` while `Row.imgFileContent` is a `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.BlobColumn Input0Buffer.imgFileContent` .

When searchin for the solution I found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/58c0b138-1f04-44fb-b72b-7610e3f40aac/datamicrosoftsqlserverdtspipelineblobcolumndata?forum=sqlintegrationservices) but I don't really understand this guys solution and If it is even applicable. I tried using `addBlobData` instead of `=`, but it requires `byte` input instead of blob data. I can't seem to find any functions which allow us to assign blob data to blob data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed my `else` code to this, seems to work, though it also seems quite inefficient. First I get blob data to a byte array, then I put that array into add blob data. The fact that I can't simply assign those values sometimes (as it breaks only sometimes) seems like a bug to me

```
else
    {
        byte[] copyData = Row.imgFileContent.GetBlobData(0, checked((Int32)Row.imgFileContent.Length));
        Row.FileImageOut.AddBlobData(copyData, checked((Int32)Row.imgFileContent.Length));
    }
```